# Can I post a comment on a status programmatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I've been reading up on the new documentation, and I've found out how to post a status as a user, and how to read a status and all it's comments, but I haven't found a way yet to post a comment. My goal is to have the backend of my application mirror exactly the interaction on Facebook, such that if a user (whose access token we have) comments on a post in our iOS app's custom UI, our server can update the mirrored post on Facebook by adding the comment as that user. It's sounds like it's possible from what I've read, but I can't figure out exactly how to do it from the documentation. Can someone explain more clearly how to post comments, and what access privileges I need to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have publish_stream permissions from the user and then you just issue an HTTP POST to https://graph.facebook.com/postID/comments?access_token=...  with a "message" post parameter equal to the comment you want to post.  Its documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) under the section titled "comments".